# Fancybox initiated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

I have a grid in which i am displaying multiple deals. Each deal has multiple sub deals. Now i have to display sub deals in a fancybox popup of a respective deal on click event. I have store the deal id in data attirbute of anchor element. Now i am stuck when sending the ajax request i cannot pass the respective deal id since i am unable to get the element which was clicked. Here is my code:

```
$('.deal_parent').fancybox({
    href    : subDealUrl,
    ajax : {
        type        : "GET",
        data        : 'deal='+{here i want to pass the deal id dynamically},
    },
    'overlayOpacity'    : '0.2',
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
});
```

I have tried passing `$(this).data('deal')` there but it doesnt worked.

Comment: do you have a click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking the fancybox differently, e.g.:

```
$('.deal_parent').click( function () {
    // NOW YOU CAN USE $(this)
    $.fancybox({
        href    : subDealUrl,
        ajax : {
            type        : "GET",
            data        : 'deal='+$(this).data('deal'),
        },
        'overlayOpacity'    : '0.2',
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
    });
});
```

I haven't tested it, the code may need adjustments.

Comment: `$(this).data('deal')` assumes that you should have a `data-deal="{something}"` attribute in your `.deal_parent` element AND a HTML5 `DOCTYPE` preferably

Comment: @JFK yes i have a markup like this i have mentioned in the text